# Что лучше: chrome.storage.sync, chrome.storage.local, или localStorage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension, localstorage

Что лучше использовать для хранения данных расширения Google Сhrome Extention,  и в чём кардинальная разница между `chrome.storage.sync` / `chrome.storage.local` / `localStorage`, с учётом возможности получения этих данных в любой вкладке?

Желательно с примером, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`localStorage` это хранилище данных стандарта HTML5.
Документация https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

`localStorage` хранит данные в виде: имя=значение (значение - строка), то есть не позволяет хранить составные объекты. При чем, типы вроде `true`, `false` будут храниться как `"true"` и `"false"`.
Обращение к данным происходит синхронным методом:

```
var x = localStorage.x;
var x = localStorage['x'];
var x = localStorage.getItem('x');
```

`chrome.storage.local` - хранилище данных экстеншена. Позволяет хранить объекты, в отличии от `localStorage`. Обращение к данным происходит асинхронно. Позволяет "слушать" изменения переменных. Документация по работе с хранилищем https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

`chrome.storage.sync` - работает как `chrome.storage.local`, но хранит данные на сервере, синхронизированные по google-аккаунту между всеми авторизованными браузерами.

Для экстеншенов предпочтительнее использовать `chrome.storage`
`local`/`sync` - зависит от ваших потребностей

Comment: спасибо, теперь я определился =)