# Куда сохранить данные с помощью расширения Chrome?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

У меня есть расширение, которое запрашивает у пользователя его логин на сайте.

Как и куда сохранить введённый логин, чтобы его можно было получить даже после перезапуска браузера?

Comment: Тут подробно расписаны виды хранилища для Chrome-extensions http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/615787/176181

Comment: @belykh Переместите этот комментарий в ответ. Ссылка хорошая, а приходящие пользователи смотрят сначала на ответ.

Comment: @Deliaz Я сначала так и сделал (ответом), а сайт автоматом сконвертировал ответ в комментарий

Comment: @Deliaz если вопрос является дубликатом его так и закрывают, а не перемещают комментарий в ответ

Comment: @belykh аналогично ↑ ↑ ↑